# Newbie in ios development

Tags: ios

I am a beginner in ios programming. How to start learning ios? Can start learning lastest ios 9 or should I start with ios 4 or ios 5 than gradually come to lastest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can start learning lastest ios 9 book or should I start with ios 4 or ios 5 than gradually come to lastest version? There are some books on swift programming also.

You should start with the latest iOS version. Install the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store and then start with Apple's [Getting Started documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/). At this point, you should learn Swift instead of Objective-C because that's the direction that Apple is going; you may need to read some Objective-C code, but once you've got the basics of Swift down it's not hard to read Objective-C.

Books are definitely a good way to expand your knowledge, but I think Apple's online documentation (much of it also available inside Xcode) is a good starting point that'll get you started without a big investment. Once you get the ball rolling, you'll be in a much better position to evaluate books for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to develop for an older version - start with the latest version.

A lot of things has changed since iOS 4 or 5, and it's better if you learn swift than objective-c.

A good book to start with is "The Swift Programming Language", by Apple - 
https://itunes.apple.com/il/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11